# Looks or keeps looking at a woman: Matthew 5:28

Tags: greek, matthew, history, translation-philosophy

ΚΑΤΑ ΜΑΤΘΑΙΟΝ 5:27-28 1881  (WHNU)

> 28 εγω δε λεγω υμιν οτι πας ο βλεπων γυναικα προς το επιθυμησαι
> [αυτην] ηδη εμοιχευσεν αυτην εν τη καρδια αυτου

English translations usually  render the verse as follows.

Matthew 5:27-28  (NASB)

> 28 "But I say to you that everyone who looks at a woman with lust for
> her has already committed adultery with her in his heart."

Matthew 5:28  Berean Literal Bible

> "But I say to you that everyone looking upon a woman in order to lust
> after her already has committed adultery with her in his heart."

From Strong's  Lexicon (Bible Hub)

who looks at

βλέπων (blepōn)

Verb - Present Participle Active - Nominative Masculine Singular

Strong's Greek 991: (primarily physical), I look, see, perceive, discern. A primary verb; to look at.

Is it possible that  Jesus was not referring to a casual immoral thought, but rather the seriousness  of one who continuously "keeps on looking" and which  may arouse passionate desire , that may lead to adultery.

**Question: Could the verse  Matthew 5:28, then be translated as follows or otherwise to infer this meaning?**

"But I say to you that everyone **"who keeps on looking"** at a woman with lust for her has already committed adultery with her in his heart."

Answer (score 2):

I would translate Matt 5:28 as:

> But I say to you that everyone looking to/upon/at a woman in order to
>   lust [over] her has already committed adultery with her in his heart.

The operative verb βλέπων (blepōn) is Present Participle Active - Nominative Masculine Singular.  [Thus, "looking" is a reasonable translation.  Note that the verb is ***not*** present continuous which would make the translation more like "continuing to look".]

Note that Jesus' injunction here is not the act of looking at a woman, but the act of looking with the intention to cultivate lustful thoughts.  The commentary by Ellicott expresses the idea this way:

> The intent is more strongly marked in the Greek than in the English.
>   It is not the passing glance, not even the momentary impulse of
>   desire, but the continued gaze by which the impulse is deliberately
>   cherished till it becomes a passion.

Comment: https://www.ntgreek.org/learn_nt_greek/inter-tense.htm